# Override Google Map Data opacity on zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have added some custom polygons to a google map, each of which have their own custom color based on some value.  When the map is zoomed out, I want the colors to be solid (I have this working without issue).  What I would like to happen, is that as the user zooms in, the polygons become opaque, letting the user see the landscape beneath the polygons.

I have tried the following (on 'zoom_changed')...

```
map.data.setStyle(function (feature) {
              return ({
                  fillOpacity: 0.1
              });
          });
```

The problem with that, is that it will also override the colors of the polygons, so then my polygons will change from color coded to all black with an opacity of .5.

Anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code above to reflect the suggestion below, but I'm still seeing the same behavior.  Colors change to gray, but I do get the opacity right, but I have lost my color coded polygons, and simply have all gray polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you only set e.g. the `fillOpacity` all the other styles will be discarded and the API-defaults will be used.

Possible solution: implement the change of the `fillOpacity` in the default styling-function:

```
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    return ({
      fillColor: feature.getProperty('color'),
      strokeColor: feature.getProperty('color'),
      //set the opacity to 1 when zoom<4
      //otherwise set it to .1
      fillOpacity: map.getZoom()<4?1:.1
    });
  });
```

...now the desired `fillOpacity` has been applied for the initial map-zoom

To apply a different `fillOpacity` based on the zoom you only have to run `setStyle` again(with the same styling-function as argument). The styling-function easily may be accessed via `map.getStyle()`

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function(){
      map.data.setStyle(map.data.getStyle());
  });
```

...that's all.

But this is not optimal, when you have a lot of features the API has to iterate over all features each time when the zoom changes, also when the changed zoom will not result in a modified `fillOpacity` (e.g. in the code above when you zoom from 3 to 2).

Better solution:

Use a property where you store the last zoom, then you be able to decide whether the styling-function must run or not.

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -28, lng: 137.883}
  });
  //that's the mentioned property
  map.set('lastZoom',map.getZoom());

  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function(){
    //do we need to update the style?
    if(this.getZoom()<4!==this.get('lastZoom')<4){
      map.data.setStyle(map.data.getStyle());
    }
    //update the property
    this.set('lastZoom',this.getZoom());
  });
```

Demo:  [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/b7u37wax/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/b7u37wax/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Also nice idea with the checking last zoom, so that we don't apply the style every time we zoom.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "opacity" style.  It needs to be either strokeOpacity or fillOpacity, depending on whether you are changing a line or a polygon.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkkr1stc/1/)

```
map.data.setStyle(function (feature) {
    return ({
        fillOpacity: 0.1
    });
});
```

See the documentation on [style options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#style_options)

Available on line geometries

- strokeColor: The stroke color. All CSS3 colors are supported except for extended named colors.
- strokeOpacity: The stroke opacity between 0.0 and 1.0.
- strokeWeight: The stroke width in pixels.

Available on polygon geometries

- fillColor: The fill color. All CSS3 colors are supported except for extended named colors.
- fillOpacity: The fill opacity between 0.0 and 1.0.
- strokeColor: The stroke color. All CSS3 colors are supported except for extended named colors.
- strokeOpacity: The stroke opacity between 0.0 and 1.0.
  strokeWeight: The stroke width in pixels.

Comment: So you are right that I didn't have the setting fillOpacity correct, but nonetheless I get the same result.  When i zoom into my map, the opacity changes, but the color of my polygons change to gray, instead of staying color coded with just a change in opacity.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.